# Жесткие ссылки в линукс

Tags: linux

Почему, когда мы выводим информацию о файлах в директории в поле информации о размере файла, который представляет собой hardlink у нас размер совпадает с размером файла, на который ссылается hardlink, но при этом суммарное значение занимаемой памяти файла и hardlink-а не удваивается?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! дополните вопрос примером, пожалуйста. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: А почему оно должно удваиваться, если фактически, данные существуют на диске в единственном экземпляре?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что по факту это один объект файловой системы и *hardlink* ссылается на один и тот же *inode*. *inode* – это объект файловой системы, содержащий информацию о владельце/группе, которым принадлежит файл или каталог, его права доступа к нему, его размер, тип файла, *timestamp*-ы отражающие время модификации индексного дескриптора (*ctime*, *changing* *time*), время модификации содержимого файла (*mtime*, *modification* *time*) и время последнего доступа к файлу (*atime*, *access time*) и счётчик для учёта количества жёстких ссылок на файл. Каждый *inode* имеет собственный номер, который присваевается ему файловой системой в момент её создания.
Чтобы в этом убедиться можете выполнить команду `ls -lih | grep file` цифры в самом левом столбце и есть *inode* файла. Затем создайте жесткую ссылку на файл и выполните `ls -lih | grep inode_number` и убедитесь, что это один и тот же файл. При создании *simlink* создается новый файл файловой системы со своим *inode*, поэтому у него другие характеристики.